# How to index word with hyphen in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I have a StandardAnalyzer working which retrieves words and frequencies from a single document using a TermVectorMapper which is populating a HashMap.

But if I use the following text as a field in my document, i.e.

```
addDoc(w, "lucene Lawton-Browne Lucene");
```

The word frequencies returned in the HashMap are:

browne 1
lucene 2
lawton 1

The problem is the words ‘lawton’ and ‘browne’. If this is an actual ‘double-barreled’ name, can Lucene recognise it as ‘Lawton-Browne’ where the name is actually a single word?

I’ve tried combinations of:

```
addDoc(w, "lucene \”Lawton-Browne\” Lucene");
```

And single quotes but without success.

Thanks

Mr Morgan.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to be able to use a stop words list, I suggest you try the PatternAnalyzer. It allows for such a list and has a prefilled whitespace pattern.

Or you wrap the whitespace analyzer and do something like this in the tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) you do something like this:

```
public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
  TokenStream stream = myWhitespaceAnalyzer.tokenStream(fieldName, Reader);
  stream = new StopFilter(stream, stopWords);
  return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the characters

see Lucene Documentation here

http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters

Comment: This might work in queryparsersyntax where the character is escaped but in my example, using addDoc(w, "lucene Lawton\\-Browne Lucene"); the output remains unchanged. I've tried a WhitespaceAnalyzer which gives me the name as one word but this doesn't count duplicates of the same word as one word.

Comment: I believe a WhitespaceAnalyzer should work fine. Can you please post some more code around the addDoc in order to clarify this?

Comment: A WhiteSpaceAnalyzer seems to give me what I want if I set all the tokens to lower case before the call to the analyser itself. But this type doesn't allow stop words which is a bit of a bind.

Comment: What is the maven dependency I need to add for TermVectorMapper?